# How to ssh with paramiko when prompted for password?

Tags: python, linux, date

whats the best way to convert linux date output to python datetime object?

```
[root@host]$ date
Wed Jun  4 19:01:58 CDT 2014
```

Please note there are multiple spaces between Jun and '4'

```
dateRaw = 'Wed Jun  4 19:01:58 CDT 2014'
sysDate = re.sub(' +',' ',dateRaw.strip())
sysDateArr = sysDate.split(' ')
sysMonth = sysDateArr[1]
sysDay = sysDateArr[2]
sysYear = sysDateArr[5]
print datetime.strptime(sysMonth+sysDay+sysYear), "%b%d%Y")
```

There has to be a less tedious way...

Comment: The title for your question is incorrect!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There should be no need to split everything up and rejoin it like that:

```
import datetime
date = 'Wed Jun  4 19:01:58 CDT 2014'
datetime.datetime.strptime(date.replace("CDT",""),  '%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y')
```

should work.  See the python docs[1] for all the date string parsing formats.

You can also use the python-dateutil library[2] which makes it even easier!:

```
from dateutil import parser
date = 'Wed Jun  4 19:01:58 CDT 2014'
parser.parse(date)
```

[1] https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior

[2] http://labix.org/python-dateutil